How to create an empty named specified column and position this column into a particular numbered position within the data frame in R
I have a data frame with 388 columns, and I have two columns in my data frame labelled as 'Longitude_E' and 'Latitude_N', containing GPS coordinates in degrees, minutes, and seconds.
I aim to create two empty columns, and, label them as 'Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E' and 'Degrees_Decimal_Latitude_N' because I want to add GPS coordinates in decimal degrees.
I know how to create two empty columns with specified names, but I can't figure out how to insert them within my data frame in a particular position using packages such as Dplyr or Tidyr.
#Create two columns with decimal degrees coordinates 

Df[,"Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E"] <- NA
Df[,"Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N"] <- NA

The columns containing GPS positions in degrees, minutes and seconds are column numbers 12 and 13.
I'd like the two new empty columns labelled as 'Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E' and 'Degrees_Decimal_Latitude_N' to be positioned as column numbers 14 and 15.

When using dplyr::mutate to create your columns you can specify the position where the columns should be inserted via .after= or .before:
Df <- matrix(
  rep(1:20, 2),
  ncol = 20
) |>
  data.frame()

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

Df |>
  mutate(
    Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E = NA,
    Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N = NA,
    .after = 13
  )
#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E
#> 1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17  19   1   3   5                          NA
#> 2  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18  20   2   4   6                          NA
#>   Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
#> 1                         NA   7   9  11  13  15  17  19
#> 2                         NA   8  10  12  14  16  18  20

And to relocate columns after they have been created you could use dplyr::relocate:
Df[,"Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E"] <- NA
Df[,"Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N"] <- NA

Df |>
  relocate(
    Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E,
    Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N,
    .after = 13
  )
#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E
#> 1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17  19   1   3   5                          NA
#> 2  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18  20   2   4   6                          NA
#>   Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
#> 1                         NA   7   9  11  13  15  17  19
#> 2                         NA   8  10  12  14  16  18  20


Thank you Stefan, I really appreciated your help
